# Django url can't work after i move it down from the list

Tags: django, django-urls, slug

I am making a blog app using Django. In my blog app, i have 6 paths. This is my app `urls.py`

```
from . import views
from .views import AddPostView
from django.urls import path
from .feeds import LatestPostsFeed

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    # path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('upload/', views.image_upload_view, name="upload"),
    path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name='add_post'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path("feed/rss", LatestPostsFeed(), name="post_feed"),
]
```

The app is working perfectly, but whenever i try to move the `path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail')` up from the `add_post` url (code below) and try to open `add_post`

```
from . import views
from .views import AddPostView
from django.urls import path
from .feeds import LatestPostsFeed

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    # path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('upload/', views.image_upload_view, name="upload"),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name='add_post'),
    path("feed/rss", LatestPostsFeed(), name="post_feed"),
]
```

suddenly i have an error saying :

> Page not found (404)
>
> No Post matches the given query.
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/add_post/
> Raised by:    blog.views.post_detail
>
> Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL
> patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> admin/
> [name='home']
> upload/ [name='upload']
> <slug:slug>/ [name='post_detail']
> ```
>
> The current path, add_post/, matched the last one.
>
> You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
> settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
> standard 404 page.

I don't understand why it happens and i am curious and want to know what has just happened. maybe there are some concepts about django urls that i don't know. Can you explain to me what happen in this error?

Comment: The problem is that `'<slug:slug>/'` will match any string. If you put that pattern at the top of the list, it will match `'add_post/'` and won't go any further down the list. It will always go to the `post_detail` view and it will try to find a post object with a slug of `'add_post'`. You need to put the `'<slug:slug>/'` pattern after `'upload/'` and `'add_post/'` in order for it to work correctly. If you change the pattern to `'post/<slug:slug>/'` for example, then you can put it anywhere in the list.

Comment: Thank you, i try to add the url `'post/<slug:slug>/'` and it works perfectly